# Creating elements with empty selectors

Tags: css, html

If I create an element with an empty selector for example `<div class="">` and another `<div>`

Can I target that specific element somehow due the blank class?

Looking in the browser inspector it reads "`div class`"

If it doesn't create any kind of class associated with the element, can it cause any problems from being there or totally ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to select an element with `class=""`

For example for this

```
<div class=""></div>
```

Use

```
div[class=""]
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JRP4n/

It seems that a class with an empty or null value is different than not having a class attribute defined at all.

So `div[class=""]` works because it truly targets a defined class which is empty.

But as mentioned in the comments, an empty class attribute is not compliant with the specifications, but interestingly it has been working in all major browsers so far. It also means it "may" stop working should any browser decides to drop support for it.

Comment: Just because it happens to be possible, perhaps, maybe, sometimes, to select using an empty selector, that does not make it even close to a good idea, the specification says "The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.", that is it, anything else that works is just luck and will eventually break.

Comment: @blankabout True, but it's interesting it works in all major browsers and seems to be more than just luck.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I did test and play around with this before I asked the question. What could be the reason for this? Can you see any useful implementation? @Arbel elaborate on your answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @Aaron It seems that a class with an empty or null value is different than not having a class attribute defined at all. So div[class=""] works because it truly targets a defined class which is empty. But as @ blankabout has mentioned, an empty class attribute is not compliant with the specifications, but interestingly it has been working in all major browsers so far. It also means it "may" stop working should any browser decides to drop support for it.

Comment: Sure this I understand.  I only asked for you to increase the content on your answer for future readers. It's an interesting question and hasn't been asked here before.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I have read the behaviour is unspecified for empty class names [see w3 HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) my experience has been that browsers will just ignore the empty attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but that link doesn't really confirm anything

Comment: I think you might be looking for confirmation of a negative. Essentially if you define an empty class name then that is what you will get, browsers will just ignore it, there is no such thing as a default class.

Comment: See Arbel's example above :)

Comment: Yep, way to go, ignore the standards and go with something because it works. Enjoy.

Comment: blankabout, you completely misunderstand my intentions :)

Answer (score 0):

In general the following applies to all [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attributes):

> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string.

It’s valid to have an empty [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) in HTML5:

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a **set of space-separated tokens** representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

A [set of space-separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) is defined as:

> A set of space-separated tokens is a string containing **zero or more** words (known as tokens) separated by one or more space characters, where words consist of any string of one or more characters, none of which are space characters.

So you can have a `class` attribute containing zero tokens:

```
<div class="">This should be valid.</div>
```

You could [omit the value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0), too:

> Empty attribute syntax
>
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

So you can have a `class` attribute without value (which equals a value with the empty string):

```
<div class>This should be valid.</div>
```

---

In CSS, you could select these elements with:

```
[class] {color:red;} /* would select all elements with the class attribute, no matter which value */
[class=""] {color:red;} /* would select only elements with empty or no value */
[class|=""] {color:red;} /* would select elements that have an empty class value, no class value or a class value beginning with "-" */
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Is there actually any use for this?

Comment: @Aaron: I can’t think of any use. Maybe if someone wants to be able to select certain elements without inventing a `class` name? ;)

Answer (score 0):

We questioned if there could be any use for this feature and I found a use.

If using js to remove all class names from an element, element is left as 'element class' so using [class=""] {x;} can target elements you have previously removed classes from.